# How does the buttonClass directive in ember.js work?

Tags: ember.js

This code:
{{bindAttr class="buttonClass:hidden"}}

[On this line](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/index.html#L48)

That bindAttr code does not appear to do anything. I can remove it entirely and the todo app works just the same as before.

What exactly is the buttonClass directive doing? There is no buttonClass property on the todos controller.

Comment: Please post the relevant section of code within the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it is not needed. It was probably there to hide the button if it had no completed tasks. But since it is now wrapped in :

```
{{#if hasCompleted}}
```

It should probably be removed.